# How to copy the value which are before a blank cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the code for getting the blank cell information but the problem is that I want to copy the data which are before the blank call.  After the blank cell there might be a value.  Here's my code:

```
Set rng = Range("6:6").Find(What:=horiz, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)    
If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Value not found in row 1", vbExclamation
Else
    rng.EntireColumn.Copy
    Range("p1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MsgBox Range("C1").End(xlDown)(2, 1).Value
```

Comment: What cells are you talking about?  Excel?

Comment: Are you sure this is VB.NET and not actually VB6?  `Set` isn't really valid in .NET.

Comment: Ok.  I updated the tags on your question to reflect that.  In the future please try to be more careful about what tags you choose.  If you choose the right ones, you'll have a much better chance of getting good answers.  Good luck!

Comment: @user1616384 what is the problem? You don't really explain what the issue is.

Comment: OK ,for example I have two set  of matrix data in excel sheet.
i,e one set of matrix data continues after one blank row from another one so when I want to select column of first set of matrix then it is selecting all data ... SO i want to copy the data which  are before blank row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really see your data set, so hard to say this is bullet proof, but from what your post says, this may be what you need.

Change

`rng.EntireColumn.Copy` (which copies the entire column)

to

`Range(rng, rng.end(xlDown)).Copy` which copies the range from the found range to the last cell before a blank.

If you want to copy all the cells above the found range, until you find a blank above, and all the cells below, write this:

`Range(rng.End(xlUp), rng.End(xlDown)).Copy`

Comment: THANKS  A LOT FOR UNDERSTANDING MY PROBLEM I AM SORRY FOR BAD EXPLANATION

Comment: copies the range from the found range to the last cell before a blank